# Accessing the columns of a pandas DataFrame via a string variable

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I've set up a little function that takes in a pandas DataFrame and a few parameters, and then attempts to create an OLS regression using statsmodels. It's designed to allow me to call it from a loop, running lots of different regressions with some simple code. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and I'd appreciate some guidance on what I need to do to make it work. Here's the function:

```
def regressReturns(rawData, predictor, horizon):
    x = rawData.eval(predictor) 
    x = sm.add_constant(x)
    y = rawData.eval(str(horizon) + '_Yr_Return')
    results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    return results.params
```

I get nothing other than a syntax error if I call it from a loop:

```
for rh in retunHorizons:
    regressReturns(rawData,'Earnings_Yield', rh)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that rawData is your DataFrame, and that what you have in your evals is the name of the column you are trying to access. If that's the case, the following will work:

```
x = rawData[predictor]
y = rawData[str(horizon) + '_Yr_Return']
```

Columns can be accessed with both as attributes, and like a dict. The first way is a bit more concise, but the second way is more flexible if you want to use variables as a column name.

Comment: Indeed they are, and your suggestions works. Thank you very much! I now get a message for some of the regressions saying that the array must not contain infs on NaNs. I know that the NaNs are at the beginning (because I don't have data on the predictors) or at the end (because the relevant time period hasn't occured (e.g. 10 yr forward return starting in 2013). How can I cut out the relevant section of both the predictor and the response so that they both have data?

Comment: @ThomasPhilips about nans: you can use pandas `dropna` method as in elyase's example, or use the `missing='drop' argument for the statsmodels OLS model. In elyase's example rows will also be dropped if there are other variables/columns with nans that are not used in the regression, even if there are no nans in the columns used for x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You can do OLS directly with pandas:

```
from pandas.stats.api import ols

def regressReturns(rawData, predictor, horizon):
    rawData.dropna(inplace=True)
    results = ols(y=rawData[str(horizon) + '_Yr_Return'] ,
                  x=rawData[predictor])
    return res.sm_ols.params
```

Comment: Do [be careful when using Pandas-provided regression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708643/unexpected-standard-errors-with-weighted-least-squares-in-python-pandas). It's often a bizarre mixture of home-cooked summary calculations and directly reported intermediate results from `statsmodels`. Things like degree of freedom for standard error calculations can lead to mismatching results, or results that seem unreproducible until you learn that there is all this hidden state regarding things like degree of freedom. It makes a compelling reason to always use other libraries' regression code.

Comment: Point well taken. Statistical algorithms are notoriously hard to code well, as they have conflicting requirements of stability, precision and speed across a very wide (and uncontrollable) range of inputs. Far better in practice to get the statistical heavy lifting done by time tested implementations, which are typically found in specialized statistical packages. Python's own statistics module is a step in the right direction, though it has hardly any functions at this point.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips, pandas uses `statsmodels` if it is installed, otherwise `scikit learn`, is just a more direct way to call the same function.